# How to use one Yii2 installation in two domains one subdomain for mobile and primary domain for desktop

Tags: yii2

I wanna make a web application using Yii2 framework. I want to make a subdomain for mobile like m.khaana.af just with one installations yii in primary domain khaana.af.

Just like mobile.de

Comment: Check Yii 2 Advanced Application Template. In this template Backend and Frontend will use one Yii2 installation.

Comment: More details please

Answer (score 0):

Yii2 advanced template is useful for building multiple domains or subdomains with one time Yii installations.

Ex:- you want to build 3 domains like example.com, m.example.com, blog.example.com

```
Yii2
  Frontend
  Backend
  Mobile
  Blog
```

Create a sub folder like above then setup Document Root of sub domain to newly created folder.

For more info about Yii2 advanced application structure
[Yii2 Advanced Structure](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-advanced#directory-structure)

I hope, you will be clear about this.

Comment: I have main and mobile sites: site.com and m.site.com.

How to display different views/themes in Yii2 for mobile and desktop devices?

May be I should using themes, but how display different views? P.S. I don't want use responsive design. Thank you!

Comment: Yes, you have to develop two separate apps, one for site.com and second for m.site.com.  Here you should create separate themes, views and assets for webpage design.

Comment: Thanks for reply you mean I have to install yii twice one for site.com and one for m.site.com? Or It is possible for just one installation of yii

Comment: if you are using yii2-basic then you have to install two times or if it is yii2-advanced-app then no need to install two times.

Comment: First setup advance temple in your machine as per YII doc and check the folder structure. You will get to know more about advance app structure.